# Expo build - Run Gradlew error - Error message: groovy.json.JsonException: Unable to determine the current character

Tags: expo, build.gradle

For context, the package versions I'm using for my app:

```
Expo: 48.0.0
Node: 16.16.0
```

**Problem:**
I am using Expo build to build my app for both iOS and Android but after applying the command:

```
eas build --platform all
```

I am getting the error from the "Run Gradlew" section as seen below:

```
Running 'gradlew :app:bundleRelease' in /home/expo/workingdir/build/android
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip
10%.
20%.
30%.
40%.
50%.
60%.
70%.
80%.
90%.
100%
Welcome to Gradle 7.5.1!
Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Support for Java 18
- Support for building with Groovy 4
- Much more responsive continuous builds
- Improved diagnostics for dependency resolution
For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/release-notes.html
To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build
[stderr] 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[stderr] 
* Where:
[stderr] 
Script '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle' line: 450
[stderr] 
* What went wrong:
[stderr] 
A problem occurred evaluating script.
[stderr] 
> Calling `[node, /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/bin.js, config]` finished with an exception. Error message: groovy.json.JsonException: Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object
[stderr] 
  
[stderr] 
  The current character read is 'i' with an int value of 105
[stderr] 
  Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object
[stderr] 
  line number 1
[stderr] 
  index number 0
[stderr] 
  info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
[stderr] 
  ^. Output: info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
[stderr] 
* Try:
[stderr] 
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[stderr] 
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[stderr] 
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] 
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[stderr] 
BUILD FAILED in 21s
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
```

After inspecting the gradle scan report, these two errors are what causing the build failure:

- 1: Task failed with an exception. Where: Build file
  '..\project\android\app\build.gradle' line: 87

  - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

    > Cannot invoke method getAbsolutePath() on null object
- 2: Task failed with an exception.

  - What went wrong:   A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

    > compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

Both the getAbsolutePath() method and the compileSdkVersion are already specified within the app\build.gradle file. The snippets from android\build.gradle are posted below:

```
def projectRoot = rootDir.getAbsoluteFile().getParentFile().getAbsolutePath()
android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.project12.techdev'
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED", isNewArchitectureEnabled().toString()...
}
```

What seems to be the issue here? The "Run Gradlew" section mentions an invalid character within Groovy.json initially but after a deep scan, the latter issues got recognized. Any advice is appreciated, thank you.